# CNN having high overfitting despite having dropout layers?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, dropout

For some background, my dataset is roughly 75000+ images, 200x200 greyscale, with 26 classes (the letters of the alphabet). My model is:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(200, 200, 1))) 
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu')) 
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(26, activation='softmax'))


model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.CategoricalAccuracy()]) 

model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=1, batch_size=64, verbose=1, validation_data=(X_test, y_test))
```

The output of the model.fit is:

```
Train on 54600 samples, validate on 23400 samples
Epoch 1/1
54600/54600 [==============================] - 54s 984us/step - loss: nan - categorical_accuracy: 0.9964 - val_loss: nan - val_categorical_accuracy: 0.9996
```

99.9+ valadiation accuracy. When I run a test, it gets all the predictions incorrect. So, I assume it is overfitting. Why is this happening, despite adding the dropout layers? What other options do I have to fix this? Thank you!

Comment: nan values in loss is an indication that there is  gradient explotion. But in some cases nan values are seen when the input data is corrupted. I had the same issue. The reason being that there was a mismatch in number of classes and number of units in final dense layer.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, do you have any suggestions on what I could do? I'm certain that there is no mismatch in the number of classes and the number of units. I'm training on the Alphabet, 26 classes - which matches the Dense output of 26 also @sreagm

Comment: If there is no issue with the input pipeline, I think it is better try a different architecture. Also it is worth trying to include a batch normalization layer?

Answer (score 1):

The only way you would get all the predictions on a held-out test set incorrect while simultaneously getting almost 100% on validation accuracy is if you have a data leak. i.e. Your training data must contain the same images as your validation data (or they are VERY similar to the point of being identical).

Or the data in your test set is very different than your training and validation datasets.

To fix this ensure that across all your datasets no single image exists in more than one of the datasets. Also ensure that the images are generally similar. i.e. if training using cell phone photos, do not then test with images taken using a DSLR or images that have watermarks pulled from Google.

It is also odd that your loss is `nan`. It may be due to using categorical accuracy. To fix this just put the metric to be 'accuracy'. This will dynamically determine the best accuracy to use. One of `[binary, categorical or sparse_categorical]`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I originally had the metric set to accuracy, but that gave me the results:

`Train on 54600 samples, validate on 23400 samples Epoch 1/1 54600/54600 [==============================] - 53s 970us/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: nan - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00`

So someone here recommended that I switch it to what it is now. I am certain that my dataset is fine, because the same code when I run it on the same but smaller dataset (but using 10 outputs rather than 26) it works fine. 

To specify my dataset is the American sign language. 26, classes one for each letter.

Comment: I believe that's the appropriate output. If your loss is `nan` your accuracy should probably be `0`. As I've said on your other questions you'll need to normalize your data (divide by 0). Generally this type of thing is the result of an error in the pipeline w.r.t. to data ingestion.

Comment: Thank you, ill give that a go. Sorry this is my first NN I'm trying to recreate so I'm a bit confused with some of the terminology. When normalizing the data, do we just normalize the X_train and X_test? That's what it seems like they're doing in [this tutorial](https://towardsdatascience.com/a-guide-to-an-efficient-way-to-build-neural-network-architectures-part-i-hyper-parameter-8129009f131b). They're setting it up like X_train /=255 .. etc

Comment: Correct. Divide the images in your train and test set by 255. See here for more details - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29853497/normalization-of-an-image

Answer (score 0):

It's totally not overfiting, look at your loss it's equal to nan. That means your gradients have exploded during the training. To see what's really happening i recommend you look at the loss after every mini-batch and see at what point the loss becomes nan.